# Referencing caller class in called class in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS and have the following problem: I have one class LoginWindow, that implements a FormPanel:

```
Ext.define('WebDesktop.LoginWindow', {
  extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

  title: Translator.get("login_window:Anmeldung"),
  layout: 'fit',
  closable: false,
  resizable: false,

  constructor: function() {
    this.callParent();
  },

  initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.loginPanel = new WebDesktop.LoginPanel(me);

    me.items = [
        me.loginPanel
    ],

    me.callParent();
  },
});

Ext.define('WebDesktop.LoginPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

  header: false,
  bodyPadding: 5,
  reset: true,

  waitMsgTarget: true,
  url: Routing.generate('_route_core_login'),

  items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: Translator.get("login_window:Benutzername"),
    name: '_username',
    width: 300,
  },
  {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: Translator.get("login_window:Passwort"),
    name: '_password',
    inputType: 'password',
    width: 300,
  }],

  buttons: [{
    text: Translator.get("login_window:Anmelden"),
    handler:  function() {

        var form = this.up('form').getForm();

        if (form.isValid()) {
            // Submit the Ajax request and handle the response
            form.submit({
                success: /* Call a function that is defined in main application class */,
                failure: function(form, action) {

                    Ext.Msg.show({
                        title: Translator.get("login_window:Benutzeranmeldung"), 
                        msg: action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response',
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR
                    });

                    form.reset();
                }
            });
        }
    }
  }],
});
```

Now in my main application class I create an instance of the LoginWindow and show it to the user. Also in this main class is a function defined, that should be called when the form of the login window has successfully been submitted. But I don't know how to put in a reference to that function. I tried to pass a reference of the caller class to the called class and save it there, but that did not work. As you can see I'm not working with the MVC architecture, I know it's not best practice...

Comment: why aren't you using best practice?

Comment: I have not found an example yet that explains the use of controllers in a satisfying way for me

Comment: How about this? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
me.loginPanel = new WebDesktop.LoginPanel();
me.loginPanel.referenceToParentWindow = me;
```

is this what you are looking for? I am very confused.

Comment: I tried this, but if I try to access this reference in the LoginPanel class it is undefined

Comment: I played around a little bit and seems to work now, so thanks